# Evaluate each environment variable and set it back in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, bash, shell-script, environment-variables, bash-scripting

I'm trying to write a shell script which reads all the environment variables, evaluate them for included env. variable with in them and re-export after evaluvation.

**Example** - I've an environment variable exposed like this:

```
echo $JVM_OPTS                 
-Djava.awt.headless=true -Xmx1600m  -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=${CONTAINER_IP} -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Duser.language=en -Duser.country=US -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSIncrementalMode -XX:+CMSIncrementalPacing -XX:CMSIncrementalDutyCycleMin=0


echo $CONTAINER_IP 
10.44.214.63
```

Now, I need to eval "**JVM_OPTS**" variable and substitute the value of ${CONTAINER_IP}  in $JVM_OPTS to 10.44.214.63. Finally, set this evaluated value back in JVM_OPTS variable.

**Sample Output:**

```
echo $JVM_OPTS                 
    -Djava.awt.headless=true -Xmx1600m  -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=10.44.214.63 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Duser.language=en -Duser.country=US -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSIncrementalMode -XX:+CMSIncrementalPacing -XX:CMSIncrementalDutyCycleMin=0
```

My Analysis so far:
I wrote the below code to do the task

```
#!/bin/bash

for path in $(printenv); do
    path=`eval echo $path`
    echo $path
done
```

printenv would give the entire env. variable along with values. I just need the name and then use the value.

How to achieve this?

Comment: Also asked at http://stackoverflow.com/q/36449213/7552

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following worked for me.

```
for path in $(compgen -e) ; do
    eval "$path=\"${!path//\"/\\\"}\""
done
```

As posted at https://stackoverflow.com/a/36449824/1925997

Answer (score 1):

Basically, the solution is in your question: eval.

```
eval export JVM_OPTS=\"$JVM_OPTS\"
```

Comment: Yes, `JVM_OPTS=eval echo $JVM_OPTS` Also gave me the same output.
But the problem is with the script.
I managed to extract each env. variable, but unable to get its actual value.

Comment: @BandiKishore - This answer appears to answer your question, and very simply, without any loops. If you require to know how to parse the `printenv` output, you should rephrase your question. If that _is_ what you need, then the following illustrates the parsing: `printenv|while l=$(line); do echo ${l%%=*} is set to ${l#*=}; done`.